# DirectX 11 missing SDK component on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, windows-8.1

I'm unable to get DirectX C++ applications working, they compile but give the following runtime error:

[image]

I have Windows 8.1 installed, but dxdiag says everything's working properly (with Direct3D/Draw/AGP texture acceleration enabled), using DirectX 11

When I run this exact same code on my Windows 8 machine it does work (same dxdiag), but would love to get it working on Windows 8.1

I'm using Visual Studio and C++. The code I'm using is geared towards Direct X 11

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag, or enabling debugging via dxcpl, you will need the debug layers DLL for Windows 8.1 (d3d11_2sdklayers.dll).  This is included with the Windows 8.1 SDK, which you can install standalone, or as part of Visual Studio 2013 RC.  Alternatively, you can disable D3D debugging temporarily (by removing the flag, or the exe name from dxcpl), which will remove the dependency on the 8.1 layers DLL.

Comment: Thanks, I'm installing it now, I installed the 8 SDK but not 8.1, I'll let you know if this fixes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you [installed the Windows 8.1 SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx)? The DirectX SDK is now part of the normal Windows SDK.